# Microphone extremely quiet

Tags: samsung, audio, samsung-galaxy-s-5, microphone, telephony

For some time, my microphone is extremely quiet when doing things like making voice messages on WhatsApp or when calling someone. I searched the internet for a solution, but I couldn't find anything except for some apps which didn't work (or only worked in the app itself but outside did nothing).
Is there a config file with the microphone volume so I can adjust it myself or some script or so?

Wired headset microphone is also extremely quiet.

---

Information that could be relevant to this problem:

Samsung G900f (S5)

Android 6.0.1 / Cyanogenmod 13

Baseband version G900FXXU1BOD3

Comment: 1. is your microphone fine for some apps say media player? meaning to ask if the volume is fine otherwise but low for say whatsapp 2. If yes, one could consider automation solution. Let me know

Comment: The volume is low for every app, but some voice recording apps have the option to set the microphone volume to a higher level, which makes the recording somewhat louder. So basically it's the same for everything.

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned here https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/development/how-to-microphone-gain-increase-s5-t3190613

Answer (score 0):

I know this is going to sound a little low tech, but have you tried blowing out or using a strong adhesive (like gorilla tape) to clean out the microphone holes? I've personally encountered the same issue caused by months of dust and pocket lint clogging up the microphone holes on a Note 4.